# What to do when you see a bad dream

Tags: practical-islam, dream

According to Islam rulings, what should one do when they see a bad dream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> It was narrated from Jabir that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “If
>   anyone of you has a bad dream, he should not tell people about how
>   Satan played with him in his dream.([Sunan Ibn Majah](http://www.sunnah.com/ibnmajah/35/21))

and

> Narrated Abu Qatada: The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "A good dream that comes
>   true is from Allah, and a bad dream is from Satan, so if anyone of you
>   sees a bad dream, he should seek refuge with Allah from Satan and
>   should spit on the left, for the bad dream will not harm
>   him."([Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/5))

So Good Dreams are from Allah Swt and one should be thankful for it but bad dreams are from satan which Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said about and told us to ask to ask refuge with Allah Swt so say Ta'awuz (ﺍﻋﻮﺬ ﺑﺎﻟﻠﻪ ﻣﻦ الشيطان ﺍﻟﺮﺟﻴﻢ )and do not tell people about it then it wont be harmful.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Jazak Allah! Thank you sister/brother! May Allah give you ajar for this and more. ameen. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Salam brother/sister.
There are 3 types of dreams :-
1)Rehmani: These are dreams from the Almighty, these carry certain messages and we do not forget them. If there is a Rehmani dream, prophet peace be upon him said that he/she should tell people about it
2)Nafsani: Dreams that come from our thinking, these are baseless and have no meanings, we can forget these dreams.
3)Shaytani: These dreams are given to us by the Shayateen or Iblis to scare us, these too have no meanings and we should not be afraid of them by any means, they're just to strike terror in one's heart.These are also called nightmares in english. We would forget these dreams too after a certain time. 
Please tell me what dream did you have, I'll try my best to answer what do they mean or are they just nafsani or shaytani and tell you what to do with it

Comment: W/salam WR brother, thank you for writing the answer. My mother said in the morning that she has heard that one should not describe that bad dream to anyone. But you just said otherwise, and mentioned the reference of a hadith. I'll be really thankful if you can give the reference number or the book it is from or where you learnt about it (that we should tell people about Rehmani dreams)? Please don't mind, but I am really scared that what if I share the dream with you and something bad happens God forbid?

Comment: I remember most of the dream? That is I remember the important bits of the dream.

Comment: No brother, you don't need to share your dream with me, if it is a nightmare, keep it with yourself, I probably misunderstood or thought you had a rehmani dream which you were afraid of, and i learnt this from a video, I don't exactly remember from which video did i learn it but this was probably the one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FODjhXzApak

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand, :)

Comment: You presented an admirable helpful answer. Jazak Allah Khaira